# Remove trailing slash from String in Java

Tags: java, string, char, arrays

I am trying to remove the last character from a string, if it is a `/`. I am using a string array, `temp[]`, to store the strings.

Here's my code:

```
char ch = ' ';
for (int st = 0; st < temp.length; st++)
{
    ch = temp[st].charAt(temp[st].length()-1);
    if (ch == '/')
        temp[st] = temp[st].substring(0, temp[st].length()-1);
    result2.append(temp[st]);
}
```

but i am getting

```
StringIndexOutOfBoundsException -1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've forgotten one key rule of defensive programming - never trust the input. You are assuming that all strings not empty.

Comment: Why are you storing your string in char[]?

Comment: do you have anything in temp? because when temp is empty you well get a null or length-1 could be out of bounds. But do the sam much simpeler with if (str.endsWith("/")) then remove last character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have empty String `""` then `temp[st].length()-1 == -1`

Answer (score 25):

> *Remove Last Character if it is / java*

```
str = str.replaceAll("/$", "");
```

Comment: It appears to do it repeatedly so I would suggest `str = str.replaceAll("/+$", "");`

Comment: To replace the trailing slash on windows (so it's a backslash) :  
`replaceAll("\\\\$", "")`  
So to replace on windows and linux:  
`.replaceAll("(\\\\|/)$", "")`

Comment: I wanted my pattern to remove `any number of additional slashes` at the end of my path string, and @PeterLawrey your pattern helped me with my requirement. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 12):

If you only want to remove a trailing '/', this should do it:

```
if (str.endsWith("/"))
    return str.substring(0,str.length()-1);
else
    return str;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do it with a regex using the [replaceFirst(regex, string)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

`String newString = tmp.replaceFirst("/$", "");`

Answer (score 2):

The StringUtils have this subtle little method called: [removeEnd(String str, String remove)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#removeEnd-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

```
String result = StringUtils.removeEnd(string, "/")
```

It will remove the end of the string only if it is this searched snippet. Otherwise this method returns the same, unchanged string.